# Hardware Acceleration browsers?

Tags: chromium

Hi I'm a university student and I'm using Ubuntu as my only OS, my laptop is a Lenovo S340 with a Ryzen 5 3500u CPU

I notice a lot more battery brain when I'm using chromium and watching video compared to my online classes through Microsoft Teams. Probably because of the lack of hardware acceleration with browsers in Linux. Is there any simple way around this? I changes chrome flags and didn't make a difference. I prefer chromium based browsers because I'm also a big stadia user

Thank you

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It's working only with x11 (not with Wayland seance). Try developer version (88 or newer) of Goggle Chrome with experimental option:

chrome://flags/#enable-accelerated-video-decode

PS: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1097029#c28 It's unstable option. Carefully.